# a WebBrowser control inside app render external webpage but ajax call inside that external page is not rendering causelist dates dropdown?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Xaml:

```
 <phone:WebBrowser 
      x:Name="causelist_web" 
      Height="578" 
      IsScriptEnabled="true"  
      Margin="10,0,0,0"
      />
```

Csharp:

```
protected override  void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {    
            String site = "http://hc.tap.nic.in/Hcdbs/search.do";
            causelist_web.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the Ajax-Call you expect to happen. (or render).

In case you are expecting a script-function (ajax or not) to run, you can invoke this method from c# using

```
causelist_web.InvokeScript("YourJavaScriptMethodInHtmlBody");
```

from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I mean the page has an ajax call in causelist date drop down.

Just run the URL in Firefox webbrowser and click on daily list button you see causelist date with dropdown. 

This is what i dont see causelist dates with dropdown when executed in windows phone.

Comment: goToSubmit() does trigger a form.submit(); not a ajax call.
your question does not show the part, where you act / call anything where you expect the call to happen. do you click "daly list" in your webbrowser control ? or did you invoke
causelist_web.Document.GetElementById("causelisttypeElementID").InvokeMember("Click");

please update your question